# References for the theory of Hadamard functions and compositions of random vectors

Tags: matrix, joint-distribution, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Recently, I fell in love with the pointwise/elementwise/componentwise/Hadamard/Schur functions and compositions of random vectors such as Hadamard squares and products of random vectors. Here is one example:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293955/normal-approximation-to-the-pointwise-hadamard-schur-product-of-two-multivariate

Unfortunately, that does not look like a very popular topic. I even read on MO that « nobody cares about the Hadamard products of (random) vectors”. I do and it appears that they are actually of primary interest in some practical applications.

Hence, I’m looking for nice, introductory references about the general theory of Hadamard functions and compositions of random vectors. Special topics of interest include:

- Multivariate analogue of the [normal product distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html) for the Hadamard product $X \circ Y$ of central or non-central Gaussian random vectors;
- Multivariate analogue of the central and non-central chi-squared distributions for the Hadamard square ${X^{ \circ 2}} = X \circ X$  of a central or non-central Gaussian random vector;
- Multivariate distribution of the Hadamard exponential of a Gaussian random vector;
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was working on Hadamard products, I had found these papers very useful. It seems relevant to your work too

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s003620100078

https://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379573900232/1-s2.0-0024379573900232-main.pdf?_tid=3509e06a-41ee-4bd1-bca4-5cfc668a7ee3&acdnat=1520922171_3b634a65ab31aede520c7295a8328555

I am surprised people think it is useless. It finds diverse use in the study of non negative matrices, and even in neural networks (LSTMs essentially make Hadamard products as part of their formulation).

A good starting point might be "Topics in Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson. They have an entire chapter devoted to the Hadamard product. The matrices for which I was finding hadamard products were not typically random, so I cannot provide too many good insights apart from the ones above

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm aware of reference 2 but there is actually nothing statistical in this paper. I'll check Horn & Johnson if possible...

Comment: Should I validate your answer??? I'd like to but if I do I fear I won't get further answers.

Comment: Upvoting an answer is a good way to recognize its usefulness and might actually encourage others to contribute.  I agree that an early *acceptance* of an answer may discourage additional answers, so it's a good idea to wait a couple of days before accepting it.